# What is the difference between struts <html: tags and struts <s: tags

Tags: struts2

I can see in some forums they are initializing struts tag as

```
<%@taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
```

and they are initializing tags as `<html:form>` etc..

but i am using struts tag as

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

and using as `<s:form>` tag. my qustion is, Is there any difference in between struts `<html:form>` tag and `<s:form>` tag, or they have only change in prefix only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much idea about Struts1, but if i am correct the one you mention `<html:form>` are from classic Struts1 and `<s:form>` is from S2.

Basically you can use any prefix to define in S2 tags like `a, b,`c etc.If you want you are free to use html as you prefix all you need to tell S2 about this like

```
<%@taglib prefix="html" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

in short its only the declaration and using `s` as prefix is kind of convention.

Answer (score 0):

The taglib declaration sets up what the prefix is, and what prefix you use makes no difference as long as you're consistent and referring to the same taglib.

Comment: There's a difference in this case, because they're different tag libs.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I was assuming he was talking about same taglib.